# Summing up donations on the household level

Tags: civicontribute

We have the following problem: If we record a donation on the individual level of a person: Let’s say there is the imaginary Byron Terry-Lee and the spouse is Megan Terry-Lee. Both are members of the household Terry-Lee. Byron Terry-Lee donates 10 $, Megan 20 $ and on the occasion of an anniversary both donate together (as a household) 30 $. I’d like to see on the household level the summed up donation for the household (respectively 60 $). Has anyone an idea how to reach that?

Thank you for looking into it.

Best regards

Esther

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for: https://civicrm.org/extensions/aggregate-household-contributions-report

Comment: Hi both of you, thanks for the answers and sorry for coming back so late but I was gone & very busy. Nevertheless I checked the description of the aggregate household contribution report thoroughly and unfortunately it's not solving our problem. What it lacks is the following: I want to see the contribution on the household level - if I call up the household Terry-Lee (s. my example) I want to have all donations by the individuals and by the household. Is that possible? I got once the hint that there is an option called inheritance which is related to that topic. Have you heard about that?

Answer (score 1):

Use Soft Credits to credit the household with a soft credit when the individual donates.

Comment: Hi Tommy, 
I checked Soft Credits as well but are not certain, do they lead to a sum up on the household level? I haven't found any mention of that. It seems to me more like an improved version of contribution pages... Thank both of you for looking in that topic and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Based on new information in your comments to Tommy and myself, I think what you're looking for is soft credits in combination with an extension that automatically soft credits a household when a member of the household contributes.  I've written an extension that does roughly that, which is [available on my Github](https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.module.automaticsoftcredit).  That said - this is a VERY rough/unfinished version of what you want, and needs work done before it can be used by a non-technical person - I also don't know if it works with newer versions of CiviCRM (it was written for 4.4).

Comment: Jon what Esther means I think is a subtotal of contributions by each of three related entities (husband, wife, household) and total contributions by all three entities. Each of the three entities can make and have recorded contributions.

Comment: And each of the three entities makes a  contribution for which it has a 'hard credit' not a 'soft credit'. The husband(s) or wife/wives make a recorded contribution on behalf of the household entity using that individual's credit/debit card or cash etc, say.

Comment: Thanx for clarifying Joe!